# Can i set internet data quota for 1 user in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, quota

I'm setting up my lounge computer for the family of 4.
I have installed timekpr and set the 2 kids up with 2hr time limits, works great.
The main user has no time limits or data limits.
The 4th person I want to set up with no time limit, but I would like to set a data allowance of 20Gb per calender month.
What software can I install that will allow me to set the data allowance of one user,
Thanks